# How do I switch off/shutdown an iPhone with a broken power button?

Tags: iphone, shutdown

The title says it all. I have an iPhone 7 with a broken power switch. Just now I needed to switch off my iPhone, but realised I can't because the switch is no good. I did ask Siri to do it for me, but she said sorry she can't do that.

Is there another way?

Comment: If it’s less than a year ago that you bought it, you’re still covered by Apple’s limited one year warranty, so if you’re lucky Apple/or the place where you bought the phone will repair/replace it for free!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Assuming you're on iOS 11:** the easiest way is to go to **Settings > General**. Swipe up until you see the *Shut Down* option at bottom.Tapping on *Shut Down* will mimic using the power button.

**If you're not on iOS 11:** then you can use Assistive Touch: go to Settings > General > Accessibility and switch on Assistive Touch. Now you'll see a *bubble* appear on the screen. You can move this around, but most importantly you can tap on it and select Device and then select Lock Screen. Doing this will give you the option to switch off your iPhone. (**Note:** You can do this with iOS 11 as well).

**Switching it back on**

To switch it back on you will have to connect your iPhone to your Mac/PC or to a charger with the Lightning cable. After a while it will power up and you'll be able to unlock it.

Comment: The OP might need to know how to switch it back on again ;)

Comment: @Tetsujin LOL Good point! I've just updated my answer. :) If you happen to know of another way, feel free to edit it and add it in.

Comment: Thanks for the addition - it's really not all that obvious if you don't already know. That's the only way I know of. BTW, the shut down in Settings is new in iOS 11 [my main phone is still on 10 so I had to go look at a test phone], useful addition.

Comment: Hmm, good point, I shouldn't assume the OP is on iOS 11. I'll mention that in my answer.

Comment: You can still only have one upvote from me ;-))

Comment: Bravo, great answer!!

Comment: Yes, bravo is right! Thanx for your great answer. :]